# My acer aspire 5532 laptop mouse

Tags: windows-7, laptop, mouse

The mouse pad on my laptop has stopped working.  It has not been turned off as we already checked.  The computer tech stated it was a windows 7 problem.  The laptop is only 3 months old.  They suggested that I try to run a recovery.  However, I put the disk in and nothing happens.  How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with my Acer Aspire One netbook's touchpad recently - I also use Windows 7.  I re-installed the driver and rebooted the machine.  "Suddenly" my touchpad was working properly.  It is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a driver issue.  Open "Control Panel" and select "Device Manager".  Look under "Mice and other pointing devices" to see if your touchpad shows up, or if there's any "Unknown Device" entries showing up.

There is a driver available at [www.acer.com](http://www.acer.com) in the "Service & Support" area.